# Алгоритм нахождения простых чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Есть данный код:

```
def foo():
    list = set()
    for i in range(300):
        for j in range(2, i-1):
            print('{} / {}'.format(i, j))
            if not i % j:
                break
            list.add(i)
    print(list)
foo()
```

Всё вроде бы ничего. НО почему-то туда попадает число:

> 99

Скрипт выводит `99 / 3` останавливается но добавляет 99 в множество.
В чем дело?

Comment: У вас `list.add(i)` выполняется сразу после `99 / 2`, потому и попадает, а что происходит после `99 / 3`  уже неважно, потому что уже добавлено

Comment: посмотрите на [простую реализацию решета Эратосфена](http://stackoverflow.com/a/193605/4279). Или вот множество других алгоритмов: [Fastest way to list all primes below N](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заведите флаг, который останется включенным, если не нашлись делители:

```
def foo():
    list = set()
    for i in range(300):
        flag = True
        for j in range(2, 1 + int(math.sqrt(i))):
            if not i % j:
                flag = False
                break
        if flag:
            list.add(i)
    print(list)

foo()
```

> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 131, 11, 137, 13, 139, 15, 143, 17,
>   257, 19, 269, 149, 271, 23, 151, 25, 277, 281, 283, 29, 157, 31, 289,
>   35, 163, 37, 293, 167, 41, 169, 43, 263, 173, 47, 49, 179, 53, 181,
>   59, 61, 191, 193, 67, 197, 71, 199, 73, 79, 83, 211, 89, 223, 97, 227,
>   101, 229, 103, 233, 107, 109, 239, 113, 241, 121, 251, 127}

Вместо флага можно использовать else ветку цикла:

```
def foo():
    list = set()
    for i in range(300):
        for j in range(2, 1 + int(math.sqrt(i))):
            if not i % j:
                break
        else:
            list.add(i)
    print(list)

foo()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: `i-1` слишком много, достаточно `int(math.sqrt(i))+1`

Comment: Но не все простые числа находит. 21 и 27 к примеру.

Comment: 21 и 27 - простые?

Comment: Извиняюсь. Я что-то не так понял)

Comment: Вообще, конечно, желательно не по полному range бегать, а по уже найденным простым числам)

Comment: Задание такое :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def isPrime(n):
  for j in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1):
    if n%j==0:
      return 0
  return 1
def search(n):
  primes = [2]
  i = 3
  while len(primes)<n:
    if isPrime(i) == 1:
      primes.append(i)
    i+=2
  return primes
```

Я вот что-то такое написал, ищет первые n простых чисел

Comment: код нерабочий, проблемы с отступами, в python это критично.

Comment: ну там отступы для функций надо сделать

Comment: @zxzxzx, под ответом есть ссылка [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/638882/edit). Ответ всегда можно улучшить, если что-то не так.